# Presto connect to Netezza

Tags: presto

is there any way I can connect to netezza database using Presto?

```
2018-08-08T13:42:06.124-0400    ERROR   Query-20180808_174205_00000_qwr8d-165   org.postgresql.Driver   Connection error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A connection could not be made using the requested protocol null.
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:57)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)
    at com.facebook.presto.plugin.jdbc.DriverConnectionFactory.openConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:59)
    at com.facebook.presto.plugin.jdbc.BaseJdbcClient.getSchemaNames(BaseJdbcClient.java:119)
    at com.facebook.presto.plugin.jdbc.JdbcMetadata.listSchemaNames(JdbcMetadata.java:72)
    at com.facebook.presto.metadata.MetadataManager.listSchemaNames(MetadataManager.java:290)
    at com.facebook.presto.connector.informationSchema.InformationSchemaMetadata.calculatePrefixesWithSchemaName(InformationSchemaMetadata.java:257)
    at com.facebook.presto.connector.informationSchema.InformationSchemaMetadata.getTableLayouts(InformationSchemaMetadata.java:222)
    at com.facebook.presto.metadata.MetadataManager.getLayouts(MetadataManager.java:350)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.iterative.rule.PickTableLayout.planTableScan(PickTableLayout.java:203)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.iterative.rule.PickTableLayout.access$200(PickTableLayout.java:61)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.iterative.rule.PickTableLayout$PickTableLayoutWithoutPredicate.apply(PickTableLayout.java:186)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.iterative.rule.PickTableLayout$PickTableLayoutWithoutPredicate.apply(PickTableLayout.java:153)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.transform(IterativeOptimizer.java:165)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.exploreNode(IterativeOptimizer.java:138)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.exploreGroup(IterativeOptimizer.java:103)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.exploreChildren(IterativeOptimizer.java:185)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.exploreGroup(IterativeOptimizer.java:105)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.exploreChildren(IterativeOptimizer.java:185)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.exploreGroup(IterativeOptimizer.java:105)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.iterative.IterativeOptimizer.optimize(IterativeOptimizer.java:94)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LogicalPlanner.plan(LogicalPlanner.java:140)
    at com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.LogicalPlanner.plan(LogicalPlanner.java:129)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryExecution.doAnalyzeQuery(SqlQueryExecution.java:341)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryExecution.analyzeQuery(SqlQueryExecution.java:326)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryExecution.start(SqlQueryExecution.java:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I tried to connect using netezza driver I am getting following error.

**etc/config.properties**

> plugin.bundles=com.facebook.presto:presto-netezza:0.117

```
2018-08-08T13:15:37.716-0400    ERROR   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer Could not resolve artifact: io.airlift.resolver.DefaultArtifact@558127d2
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve artifact: io.airlift.resolver.DefaultArtifact@558127d2
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PluginManager.createClassLoader(PluginManager.java:284)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PluginManager.buildClassLoaderFromCoordinates(PluginManager.java:274)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PluginManager.buildClassLoader(PluginManager.java:239)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.java:154)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PluginManager.loadPlugins(PluginManager.java:142)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.run(PrestoServer.java:117)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.main(PrestoServer.java:67)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no (official) Presto plugin for Netezza yet (that I know of).
You can write one, or [pay someone else to write one](https://prestosql.io/resources.html#support).

Comment: I have been looking into this forked repo https://github.com/wyukawa/presto/tree/netezza-connector however it's not helping. I am not able to built the netezza-connector. it throws lots of errors.